# What characters do I need to unlock to earn the Alter Ego trophy in Lego Marvel Super Heroes?

Tags: lego-marvel-super-heroes

For the most part, playing Lego Marvel Super Heroes has been a fun, joyful experience. However, there is one trophy I am having issues with: Alter Ego. It says to perform all big Lego figure transformations, but so far I have only found Hulk, Venom, & Stan-Hulk. Who am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing Red Hulk. According to the [gamesradar guide](http://www.gamesradar.com/lego-marvel-super-heroes-character-unlocks-guide/?page=6), you unlock him after battling him. Step into the beam of light in the 
northwest corner of the Industrial District, then fight him with another big character.

[image: red hulk fight location]

Answer (score 0):

The big transforming characters include:

- Hulk
- Red Hulk
- Stan Hulk
- Venom
- Doc Connors / Lizard

Recently got this achievement via the above characters when playing off Steam.